# Xamarin App Google Play Store Incompatible Chromebook VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, google-play, chromebook

I have developed an Android app using Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin Forms, all patched with the latest updates. For verification on an Android device, I purchased an Asus C214M Chromebook and published to it from within Visual Studio. To boost my confidence level, it published and ran both debug and release versions of my app.
In the process of publishing to Play Store, I added d8 as the dex compiler and release still runs on my Chromebook.Once it is published to Play Store it shows compatibility with 13,060 devices and there are no exclusions. When searching for Chromebook or Asus my device does not show up and no Chromebooks show as compatible.
Research and testing experience show that Xamarin apps are compatible with Chromebook, so what could I be missing in the manifest or compiler settings? The link is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.linkemupllc.wetyourwhistel. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"When searching for Chromebook or Asus my device does not show up and no Chromebooks show as compatible."* - I'm not familiar with this problem. When you look for compatible apps on your Chromebook, does it seem to list "all the usual apps", similar to checking on a Samsung or other popular device?  Can you locate other Xamarin apps, see if they have same problem? My client's Xamarin Forms app is ["LiveCaddie - MyGolfApp"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mappingindustries.LiveCaddie&hl=en_US&gl=US). This was just updated, though still targets an older Android version.

Comment: Interesting. I am on my Win10 development machine and browse over to that app on Google Play. It says compatible on all of my devices including Google Octopus (Asus Chromebook). When looking up Wet UR Whis(tel), it shows as incompatible with Google Octopus. Can you check on the compiler and manifest settings on the LiveCaddie app?

Comment: Is it possible that LiveCaddie is using the AndroidX nuget package? I finally saw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/androidx-migration while searching this morning. Trying that later today.

Comment: Yes, we use Xamarin.AndroidX nugets. I forgot we updated to that, and updated the target, when we started using MS appcenter. Target Android version: Android 11.0 (API Level 30 - R). Minimum 5.0 / Level 21. Platform Tools 31.0.3.

Comment: What do your Linker properties say? After adding AndroidX, which I didn't really need, I was getting bundle errors saying "no aab file." Regardless of what changes have been made, Chromebook still doesn't show as supported.

Comment: Change Android Options / Android Package Format to "bundle". This generates an aab instead of an apk. apk support is going away from play store; only use that during development.

Comment: Using aab now and it compiles consistently. It looks like the device support issue is that it only shows two arm listings under native platforms. I have all four checked in Advanced. Should I use dx compiler instead of d8?

Comment: We're still using d8. I don't see anything in build options or AndroidManifest.xml that specifies which devices to support. So I don't know what determines that in this new way of doing things.

Comment: found https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5388 and hope unchecking arm64 will fix things up, we shall see ...

Comment: Ah ha! I did not scroll down far enough to see the "Advanced" option. LiveCaddie has all 4 checked. And the csproj has `<AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;x86;x86_64;arm64-v8a</AndroidSupportedAbis>`.

Comment: It now shows four but doesn't list Chromebook as supported. Publishing to see how it works out, maybe so. Thanks for the help.